# Python parsing using BeatifulSoup error

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

When I run this code, I get an error
soup = BeautifulSoup(sources, "lxml")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

def html_pin():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://FULL_URL')
    sources = browser.page_source
    browser.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sources, "lxml")
    print(soup)

html_pin()
```

Please tell me what is the problem in my code? I think it's data type error, but when I tried to apply type(sources) function, I get responce class 'str'

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: Thanks alot, Chris!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `bs4` module, giving it a custom `BeautifulSoup` alias and then trying to call/instantiate this aliased `bs4` module.

Instead, you need to **import `BeautifulSoup` class from the `bs4` module**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

Note that modern IDEs really help to avoid this kind of problems, here is what I see in PyCharm when I paste your code into the editor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def html_pin():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://FULL_URL')
    sources = browser.page_source
    browser.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sources, "lxml")
    print(soup)

html_pin()
```